# Python memory consumption when using pickle.load vs process memory usage

Tags: python, performance, memory-management, pickle, ram

I'm not very familiar with Python memory management ou profiling but I'm in a weird situation and can't find any clear explication.

I'm trying to load a large ML Model (1.4 GB) using pickle in my Python code (3.7). When I call pickle.load, my process ram usage increase of around 8GB (according my task manager). I can easily understand that the pickle version on disk should be smaller than the object fully loaded in Python but the difference seems me excessive so I used Pympler to check the size of my model in my Python code and I got around 5GB.

I would like to understand why I get this 3GB difference:

- There is a problem with Pickle?
- Pympler doesn't count all the objects accurately?
- My task manager doesn't report the ram consumption the same way Pympler count it?
- ...

If you have another ideas to profile my code, feel free to answer.

Thanks

Comment: I'd go for your third option. Depending on the OS, more RAM may be allocated than needed, or there was temporary more RAM needed for some processing of the contents of the pickle file, and that RAM has not yet been released back to the OS (as it could be used again by the program).

Comment: I don't know Pympler, but you could always try and run the [garbage collector](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) once the pickle file has been loaded and unpickled, and then check the memory usage. It may not make a difference, as per my above comment.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use the garbage collector and nothing changed. Also the memory consumption is the same on my laptop and on the server that is running the application (different OS etc...) so I think I missing something